# Flash Canvas responsive animation size

Tags: javascript, html, flash, animation, canvas

Is it possible for an animation built with Flash Canvas to be responsive in the browser? By that I mean that I would like both the canvas and the animation itself to re-size themselves based on the size of the browser window while maintaining the original aspect ratio.

The code I get from publishing my canvas is the following and although I've been trying all day to figure this out, I can't get it right.

```
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib.test_1();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);
}
</script>
```

and

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="360" style="background-color:#FFFFFF"></canvas>
```

Can someone please help me? I don't have a lot of experience with java script or canvas and my attempts at updating the code haven't gotten me too far. With the help of another post here on stackoverflow I managed to have my canvas be responsive, but not the animation too. The animation just stayed in the same spot. Thank you very much in advance! Bellow is the code that made my canvas responsive if its any help:

```
<script>
var canvas, stage, exportRoot, myCanvas;

function init() {
    canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    exportRoot = new lib.test_1();

    stage = new createjs.Stage(canvas);
    stage.addChild(exportRoot);
    stage.update();

    createjs.Ticker.setFPS(lib.properties.fps);
    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", stage);

    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    myCanvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myCanvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;

    window.addEventListener("resize", resizeCanvas, false);

    function resizeCanvas (e) {
    var myCanvas = document.getElementById("canvas");

    myCanvas.width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
    myCanvas.height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
}

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works on the Adobe Forums. It's not 100% perfect but it does the job:
https://forums.adobe.com/message/6405264

Basically just doing it through CSS and adding a width of 100% to your canvas scales both the canvas and the animation properly. So your canvas would look something like this:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width="720" height="660" style="background-color:#FFFFFF; width: 100%;"></canvas>
```

The issue with this solution is that while it scales both the canvas and the animation, it doesn't scale it as a vector so the quality may vary. In my situation, the animation is only about 10kb so I'm going to create it in about 3 different sizes, 300px apart to help with that.

A side note which may help some with more experience in javascript is that if you put all of your movieclips and animations into one parent one, when you publish it from flash you'll see something like this within the first few lines of code in your .js file:

```
this.my_anim_container.setTransform(360,329.2,2,2,0,0,0,0,8.6);
```

The 2 "2"s control the scale of your animation, so if you were to change them to 3 for example, your animation would now be enlarged. Figuring out a way to modify that based on your browser size would be even better, but I personally don't have the javascript knowledge for it.